# Confusing For-loop with timeout inside and closure

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, for-loop

So, I made a container div, inside of that div I had a script dynamically create 113 divs with the class name of 'fragment'. Now, everything was in order, I specifically made those 113 divs very tiny, about 5X5 pixels. Then I placed them in container so they spelled out a title. All the divs are in an array called **divs**. So divs is an array with 113 elements.

Now here is where things got confusing, I wanted to make those divs hide behind the browser's invisible area, I achieved this by giving the 'fragments' absolute positioning and styled them to hide eg: `divs[45].style.left = -600';`, after that, I created a script that would run a **for-loop** and inside of that for-loop I wanted each little element to go back to it's spot after a delay. However, I had to use closures for that because inserting a `SetTimeout()`inside of a for-loop is weird.

```
for (i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) 
        {
            (function(j) 
             {
                setTimeout(function () 
                {
                    divs[j].style.left = divs[j].offsetLeft + 550;
                }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000));
            })(i); //Pass current value into self-executing anonymous function
        }
```

I can't wrap my head around the code above. I thought that the area where`Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)` is written is to specify the delay in ms. However, if I enter 1000, it will move all 113 elements at once. I don't understand this, shouldn't it wait 1 second before moving unto the next element in the array? By the way, the code is working fine, what ends up happening is that the elements move in randomly giving the title a very cool effect HOWEVER. Closures to me is confusing enough and to me it seems like really odd behavior.

Would someone be so kind as to explain this why this happens, why do all elements move in at once if I take out `Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)`, as opposed to simply having one element move in every second or so... *

**EDIT**
My question is not about closures, it is about why does taking out `Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)` and replacing it with say '1000', cause all of the elements to move in at once, as opposed to one by one with an interval of 1000ms.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops.3A_A_common_mistake

Comment: You need to change the approach here, have a function that calls itself with a setTimeout... that way it will call once, then wait.. call it again and wait and so on. You would also pass a parameter or two for example the divs.length and var i;

Comment: Jon already answered your question, all the timeouts fire one after the other, there is no delay because the for loop does not wait for each timeout,..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add the elements in sequence, you need to do it recursively. If you use a `for` loop then you will be "simultaneously" scheduling a bunch of timers. They will all start counting down at the same time, and they will all finish as soon as possible, without regard for each other.

Here's an example of how to schedule timers in sequence:

```
var things = [1, 2, 3];

(function next(array) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        var item = array[0],
            remaining = array.slice(1);
        console.log(item);
        if (remaining.length > 0) {
            next(remaining);
        }
    }, 1000);
}(things));
```

If you're doing a lot of asynchronous work, or if you would like to approach async tasks similar to sync ones, try out [Async](https://github.com/caolan/async#eacharr-iterator-callback). It offers some nice looping mechanisms:

```
async.eachSeries(things, function (thing, callback) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log(thing);
        callback();
    }, 1000);
}, function () {
    console.log('all done');
});
```

Comment: thanks, Jon is telling me the same thing but I'm kinda slow and can't understand why. It was my understanding that for-loops didn't start again until everything within it was executed. So I thought the one second delay would halt the execution of the next iteration.

Comment: Nope. It just keeps going. `for` loops are much more useful for synchronous programming than async.

Comment: You don't need to do this recursively... My answer is a simple modification to the OP's code and works perfectly fine.

Comment: You aren't guaranteed that time interval for long-running applications. Everywhere you use `setTimeout` you are affected by the same timer inaccuracy due to CPU load. Waiting until the last timer has finished to start the next one only guarantees that you'll be waiting at least the amount of time specified, meaning longer running applications will likely take much longer to execute on average than they should be, whereas the average delay between executions will be much more accurate when starting all of the timeouts at the same time.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my last comment because my fiddles were not convincing enough: Here is a much better recursive one: http://jsfiddle.net/g9u4z0ex/1/ and iterative one: http://jsfiddle.net/a3kdLo7z/1/

Comment: The recursive one shows that there is always a 100ms interval between iterations: "Timeout at: 102, Computation start: 0 103, Computation end: 0 232, Timeout at: 333, Computation start: 1 333, Computation end: 1 456,  Timeout at: 557 ..."

Comment: Whereas the iterative one shows that timers quickly start "piling up": "Timeout at: 55, Computation start: 0 55, Computation end: 0 179, Timeout at: 191, Computation start: 1 191, Computation end: 1 342, Timeout at: 353 ...". It depends on your requirements, they are different answers.

Comment: I am using a tablet and the results for the recursive one are way off -- almost twice as much time being taken as the iterative one

Comment: That is an accurate observation.

Answer (score 1):

All the setTimeout's are instantiated at (pretty much) the same time, and because they all have a 1 second delay, they all kick in at (pretty much) the same time.

Comment: ohhhh, okay, would you mind explaining in more detail though? I thought the for-loop didn't end until it got to the end of the current loop. Would a while loop change this?

Comment: The `for` loop keeps going. It doesn't know that you're doing asynchronous work in its body.

Comment: The for loop does end. The `setTimeout()` calls execute asynchronously. A `while` loop would be no different.

Comment: JS fires a setTimeout and sticks it in a queue, but nowhere does it say that JS is going to wait for the timeout to kick - this is one sure way to hang the system.

Comment: you could use a setTimeout to call a setTimeout

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so you want something like this... http://jsfiddle.net/92xx7u21/

The Javascript:

```
var oDivs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

window.doit = function(iLength, iCounter){
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(oDivs[iCounter]).width(($(oDivs[iCounter]).width() - 10) + "px");
        iCounter++;
        if (iCounter<iLength) {
            doit(iLength, iCounter);
        } else {
         alert('done');   
        }
    }, 1000);
};

doit(oDivs.length, 0);
```

Basically this is a self calling function, you start it once with the bottom line and then it will call itself until it has reached the length of the elements.. It could be cleaned up a little, but tried to keep it simple.. You will need to add your random time again as i kept this at 1 second per loop.

Being i did not have any of your other code, i've done this with jQuery to make it a simple example and also just adjusting the width in this case.

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty sure you understand given the previous answers; This is only a modification to your code to do what you want and may even help you to understand further:

```
for (i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) 
        {
            (function(j) 
             {
                setTimeout(function () 
                {
                    divs[j].style.left = divs[j].offsetLeft + 550;
                }, j * 1000); // simply multiply j by 1000
            })(i); //Pass current value into self-executing anonymous function
        }
```

Edit (explanation): setTimout accepts a delay in milliseconds (1/1000th of a second), and `j` is between `0` and `divs.length-1`. By multiplying this value by the amount of milliseconds to delay between actions, you end up giving it the total amount of milliseconds to wait for each execution beginning from the moment the above code is executed.

Comment: Would anyone be able to elaborate on why this was down-voted?

Comment: I really loved your solution, it's super clever. btw I didn't downvote you, but my guess is someone did because you didn't address what the other two answers did. I would upvote you if I could though, just because you solved the 'potential' issue by changing one line. Nice!

Comment: Alright, thanks for the feedback. I'm happy as long as someone appreciates the answer :)